# Selenium Google driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Am getting an error when am calling chrome path..

How can in work selenium on google chrome?[enter image description here][1]

**CODE:**

---

```
package web;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class    ChromeDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://pms.kruxsoft.com/redmine/");

}

 }
```

> **" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver
>       at web.ChromeDriver.main(ChromeDriver.java:14) "**

Comment: Its your path to your chrome driver try forward slash / instead of backslash \

Answer (score 0):

Change the Class Name to something else.
As ChromeDriver is already a class in selenium package.
And you cant use the same classname